# Will connect to network and internet, but doesn't identify local network

Tags: windows-7, networking, router

I have a router connected to the cable modem which provides internet access. All wi-fi connections are working fine. I just connected a laptop to the router (via cable) and it identified the local connection properly and internet was OK also.

But in one of the computers (the one I'm using right now, connected via cable), it simply won't identify the local connection. The network icon detects the connection as OK (both local and internet), but the status message shows no connection at all.

I can ping and access all network elements, and even map network drives, but Windows simply won't "see itself" as connected to a local network.

Comment: have you tried right clicking the lan icon and clicking troubleshoot?

Comment: err, so you can ping.. can you access trhe internet? you're not really clear. the only fault you state is that windows won't say you're connected.

Comment: Yes, I can ping, I can access the internet. I tried the 'troubleshoot' method and it doesn't detect any problem. This image shows how weird it is: http://imgur.com/um3R04O